# How to insert a floating button on top right corner of screen in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using only plain javascript, how to insert a button that will always be floating in the top right corner of the window above other elements ?

So far I got:

```
var button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Title";
button.style = "margin-top:0%;right:0%;position:absolute;"
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `top` instead of `margin-top` and set a high `z-index`

```js
var button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Title";
button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:absolute;z-index: 9999"
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Every other answer missed the `z-index` part. +1 for that!

Comment: If I run this snipped on, let's say stack overflow, the button will be displayed on the bottom of the page instead of the top ...

Comment: @Antzi Why would it behave like that?

Comment: @Antzi I just tested that with a userscript and it worked perfect here on SO

Comment: @Antzi In this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/4r9upcug/, is a userscript. Run it with for example Tampermonkey and you'll see it works here on SO

Comment: @LGSon Do you have an idea on why it would behave differently when run from the console ?

Comment: @Antzi Actually no, but since you are not going to do it that way (I guess), I don't see why that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, but instead of using the `margin-top` property, use the `top` property and use `position:fixed;` instead of `position:absolute;`.

```js
var button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Title";
button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:fixed;"
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the positioning to fixed and the top to 0

```
button.style = "top:0%;right:0%;position:fixed;"
```